# PHP write txt file from input with multiple field

Tags: php

Sorry for my english! I found the below code on stackoverflow and I just try to add more field (I need 4) without success. My 2 other fields stay blanck on my data.txt. How can I easily add 2 fields ? Thank you in advance for your help.

Form :

```
<form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<input name="field2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
$data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
}
}
else {
die('no post data to process');
}
```

Comment: I only see 2 input fields here? Where did you added the other twos? in the form?

Comment: Which "2 other fields"?

Comment: oups, i copy/pasted the original code. I tried to add 2 fields in the form and in the php file, like this : "if(isset($_POST['field1']) &&isset($_POST['field2'])) &&isset($_POST['field3'])) &&isset($_POST['field4'])) {

Comment: `$data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";` did you change this line as well, and update your question with new code

Comment: @Francky [edit] your question and add your real code. Show us where you put the two extra fields and what you changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if 4 input is there, say:-

```
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<input name="field2" type="text" />
<input name="field3" type="text" />
<input name="field4" type="text" />
```

then change

```
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    ...
    ...
}
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']) && isset($_POST['field3'])  && isset($_POST['field4']) ) {
    $data = "{$_POST['field1']}-{$_POST['field2']}-{$_POST['field3']}-{$_POST['field4']} \n";
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the fields to the HTML form too:

```
<form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<input name="field2" type="text" />
<input name="field3" type="text" />
<input name="field4" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
```

And, besides adding them to the if statement, add them to the line that gets the data from the `$_POST` variable:

```
$data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . '-' . $_POST['field3'] . '-' . $_POST['field4'] . "\n";
```